# Hugo Posts not displaying

Tags: go, hugo, toml

Using [Hugo Quickstart](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/quick-start/), I was able to up and running set up a blog and even wrote a post. When I run either `hugo server -D` or `hugo server -D --watch --verbose` I can see my post on localhost. But when I run only `hugo server` my blog loads only the Title and no posts. I have generareted the necessary files using `hugo server`. 
What should I do such that when I run `hugo server` everything loads?

Comment: We need to see the code.

Answer (score 29):

In your content/posts/, look for the field `draft` in the front matter(should be at the top of every file in posts folder). The front matter should be similar to

> title: "My First Post"
>
> date: 2018-08-14T20:08:02+05:30
>
> draft: true

Replace `true` with `false` for `draft`. Now run `hugo server` and check. You should be able to see your post now.

It seems by default, the posts that are being created in your content folder have `draft` set as `true`. hugo will not show these as web pages by default as these are drafts and not ready for publishing yet. To show these drafts you have to pass `-D` flag to `hugo server`, which is why you are able to see your posts on running this command.

If you want to set `draft` as `false` for every newly created post, you will have to set `draft` field in `archetype/default.md` as `false`.

Comment: This post actually helped on my main website, as I had forgotten to remove the draft boolean. Didn't know about the default.md thing though, might come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not: In my case, it did not work until I completely rebooted my machine. After that, the post was rendered. So maybe try this as well :-)